# Inserindo em lista circular

Tags: c

Estou com dúvidas nesse código da função de inserir lista circular.

```
tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
 //Se a lista estiver vazia
 if(p==NULL)
     return novo_no;

 tipo_lista* r = p; //Para manter a referencia ao primeiro elemento
 while (p->prox != NULL)
 {
     p = p->prox;
 }
 p->prox = novo_no;
 return r;
}
```

Ela não está funcionando corretamente e estou com dúvidas se é nessa linha do `NULL`.

Comment: Essa lista não é circular. Uma lista circular não tem fim; digamos que o _último elemento_ aponta para o primeiro, não para nulo

Comment: Você fala de uma lista duplamente ligada ou circular? Se for circular de fato, o while é um loop infinito, pois sempre haverá um next. Neste site ( >https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/circular_linked_list_algorithm.htm ), uma lista circular é definida como tendo uma cabeça, o que torna possível a inserção no início. No link há um exemplo de inserção.

Comment: Você diz: `novo -> prox = novo;`?

Comment: @FilipeOlegario circular apenas.

Comment: @LucasTrigueiro por favor dá uma resposta nessa. Não estou conseguindo fazer função a lista ligada, nem imprimir, nem inserir, baseado no `main` que você tinha feito, só falta essas duas funções.

Comment: Primeiro preciso saber em que posição você está tentando inserir, começo? fim? ordenado?

Comment: inserir normalmente começo, 1,2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a lista deve ser circular apenas, não há inicio nem fim. Neste caso, adicione o novo no em qualquer lugar. O código seguinte o adiciona entre o no passado como parâmetro e seu sucessor.

```
void inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
 //Se a lista estiver vazia
 if(p==NULL)
     return;

 novo_no->prox = p->prox;
 p->prox = novo_no;
}
```

Como não vi referência a um elemento anterior, assumo que a lista não é duplamente ligada.

Comment: Compilou sem erro, porém não aparece nada na tela.

Comment: Como é a função de impressão para poder imprimir na tela?

Comment: Você quer imprimir um campo do nó? Exemplo, o seu tipo_lista seria definido assim(?): struct tipo_lista { tipo_lista *prox; int chave; }

Comment: se for, voce pode fazer printf("%d", p->chave).